# The program '******' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install '******', Though it's already installed?

Tags: apt

I am trying to use **omniidl**, and it is already installed. But when I am trying to use it it's again asking to install the package. Any help please.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sudo apt install --reinstall omniidl`

The inital error usually means a missing binary or link. Reinstalling the package will fix most common problems.